# Aspect not executed in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-aop

I'm coding a website that will be almost fully protected by login (I'm using Spring Security for it). There are certain pages that are not protected, though (home page, login page, registration page, forgotten password page, ...) and what I'm trying to achieve is:

- If the user is not logged in when accessing these non-secured pages,
  show them normally
- If the user is already logged in, redirect to the
  home page (or to the page specified in the `redirectTo` annotation element)

Of course I want to avoid to put this in every single controller method:

```
if(loggedIn())
{
    // Redirect
}
else
{
    // Return the view
}
```

And for this reason I would like to use AOP.

I created the Annotation `@NonSecured` and I coded the following Aspect:

```
@Aspect
public class LoggedInRedirectAspect
{
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Around("execution(@my.package.annotation.NonSecured * *(..))")
    public void redirect(ProceedingJoinPoint point) throws Throwable
    {
        System.out.println("Test");
        point.proceed();
    }
}
```

Example annotated method:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HomeController
{
    @NonSecured(redirectTo = "my-profile")
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(Model model,
                        HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception
    {
        // Show home page
    }
}
```

applicationContext.xml important bits:

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="my.package" />

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class="true" />

<bean id="loggedInRedirectAspect" class="my.package.aspect.LoggedInRedirectAspect" />
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true">
    <aop:include name="loggedInRedirectAspect" />
</aop:aspectj-autoproxy>
```

The problem is that the method `redirect(...)` in the aspect never gets called. <s>Aspects in general are working fine, in fact the following method in the aspect will get called:</s> The following advice gets called but doesn't get called for the controller methods.

```
@Around("execution(* *(..))")
public void redirect(ProceedingJoinPoint point) throws Throwable
{
    point.proceed();
}
```

Am I doing something wrong in my pointcut?

Thank you.

**Update:** the last snippet in this question gets called but still doesn't get called for the controller methods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@satoshi, I think the problem that you are having is because you are using Spring-AOP and it can create AOP proxies only for beans with interfaces - and in your case the controllers do not have an interface.

The fix could be to use compile time/load time weaving using AspectJ and to not use Spring AOP OR to have cglib jars in the classpath and to force cglib based proxy creation :

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>
```

Update:
Compile time weaving can be done using a maven plugin, the showWeaveInfo configuration will show exactly which of the classes have been weaved:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.10</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
                <goal>test-compile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <outxml>true</outxml>
        <verbose>true</verbose>
        <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
        <aspectLibraries>
            <aspectLibrary>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            </aspectLibrary>
        </aspectLibraries>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Can you debug with a breakpoint in Controller class @satoshi - if a proxy has been successfully created with cglib like in your case, you should see it reflected in the type of your controller class, in the debug variables(with eclipse). If the type does not seem to be a proxy, then the CGLIB has not taken effect - I would suggest using compile time weaving - you then have the verbose option of weaver turned on to see which classes are actually getting weaved

Comment: You're right @BijuKunjummen, it seems like the proxy doesn't get created for the controller (the type is HomeController and I can't see any call to any proxy/aop method in the stack trace). So, as you say, CGLIB has not taken effect. I'm sorry but I'm new to Spring, how can a compile time weaving help me? And how can I use it? Thanks

Comment: I have updated my answer @satoshi with details on compile time weaving - I couldn't fit into a comment window, that is the reason to update the answer with details of compile time weaving using maven.

Comment: Hello @BijuKunjummen, I finally came back from some time off. I added your snippet to my maven configuration (pom.xml) and now it works! The only problem is, I don't understand what I've done. I would really like to know why this change makes it work! Thank you very much, anyway :)

Comment: Also, now my unit tests for DAOs (where JPA is involved) fail with errors like org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: No entity found for query
 at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:309)
 at org.springframework.orm.jpa.aspectj.JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect.ajc$afterThrowing$org_springframework_orm_jpa_aspectj_JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect$1$18a1ac9(JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect.aj:15)

Comment: @satoshi - spring has aspects which translate the basic JPA exceptions to runtime exceptions, these aspects are taking effect here - are you sure, this is not expected, in this specific trace it basically says that the JPA query does not have any results.

Comment: In fact that JPA query has no results but the exception is catched so that shouldn't happen..

Comment: Okay. This is expected behaviour, the Spring JPA related aspects would transform the checked JPA exception to a runtime exception, instead of catching the normal JPA checked exception catch the EmptyResultDataAccessException exception instead

Comment: Here is a reference to this at the Spring site: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-exception-translation

Comment: Thank you very much, catching that exception solves the problem! One last thing: how can I access one of my components in the aspect? I tried with `@Autowired` and implementing the `ApplicationContextAware` interface and use the `ApplicationContext.getBean()` method but I always get `NullPointerException`. I need this component (`UserService`) to check whether the user is logged in or not. It's included in the context with `<context:component-scan base-package="my.package" />`. Thanks!

Comment: @Autowired may not work in an aspect - as aspects are not managed by Spring, a way to inject dependencies into an aspect is using the aspectOf factory method - here is a sample from AspectJ in action book:`<bean id="cacheAspect" class="ajia.caching.CacheAspect"
factory-method="aspectOf">
<property name="cache" ref="cache"/>
</bean>`

Answer (score 0):

Usually what I would use an interceptor and not an aspect for this purpose. For example, create a RequestInitializeInterceptor which would check the security principal and redirect accordingly. Aspects is an overkill for this job. The interceptor will act as a front controller for every request to specific controllers and decide if it is allowed to transfer the request or not.

```
 public class RequestInitializeInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

  // Obtain a suitable logger.
  private static Log logger = LogFactory
      .getLog(RequestInitializeInterceptor.class);

  /**
   * In this case intercept the request BEFORE it reaches the controller
   */
  @Override
  public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
      HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
    try {

      logger.info("Intercepting: " + request.getRequestURI());

      // Your logic to redirect accordingly
     if (userAuthenticated) {
       response.sendRedirect(URL);
       return false;
    }
      return true;
    } catch (SystemException e) {
      logger.info("request update failed");
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Abhi. I guess I omitted an important point. The `@NonSecured` annotation has a "redirectTo" element, where I can specify where to redirect the request when the user is already logged in. I updated the original question. I don't see how can I use an interceptor given this requirement...

Comment: The interceptor will intercept all get requests and you can get the security principal from the request to evaluate if the user is authenticated or not and depending on the user status simply do response.sendredirect

Comment: But this means that I have to code all the decision logic in the interceptor and I think it's a very dirty way to do it, isn't it? Having plenty of `if` just to detect if the request needs a redirect...

Comment: Understanding your question correctly it would be just one if condition right. "If the user is already logged in, redirect to the home page" else do whatever... In any case that is your application logic and it would be same for aspects as well :)

Comment: Well, but this logic has to happen only on specified pages (login, registration, etc.) so in the interceptor I have to check whether to apply the "filter" or not.

Comment: Yes just check for the authentication logic :)

Comment: I want to avoid to do stuff like `if(request.getPathInfo().equals("/registration") || ...) { /* Authentication logic */ }`, it's a bad approach IMO

Answer (score 0):

What worked for *me*, please check following points:

- `aspectjweaver.jar` is on classpath (version 1.6.8 or later)
- Aspect class is annotated with both `@Aspect` and `@Component`
- You enabled spring aspectJ-auto-proxy

Java config:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("io.mc.springaspects")
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class SpringConfiguration {
}
```

Aspect:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class AnnotationAspect {
   ...
}
```

Maven:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
  <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
  <version>1.8.9</version>
</dependency>
```