# Aspects not getting executed

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, spring-aop

We have an annotation on a function as follows

```
public class AnInterfaceImpl implements AnInterface {
    @FairThreadUsageByEntity(entityName = "XYXYXYX",
    numberOfThreads = 1)
    public Report getReport(final String One, final String Two) {
        //implementation.
    }
}

public interface AnInterface {
    String BEAN_NAME = "AnInterface";   //used for injection in spring.
    Report getReport(final String One, final String two);
}
```

Spring configuration:

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
<bean class="com.amazon.utils.fairthreadusage.aspect.FairThreadUsageByEntityAdvice" />
```

The annotation is implemented as an aspect. Basic functionality is to limit the number of thread used by a particular type of functionality, let us say download. Below is the code for annotation `FairThreadUsageByEntity`:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface FairThreadUsageByEntity {
    public String entityName();
    public int numberOfThreads();
}

@Aspect
public class FairThreadUsageByEntityAdvice extends FairThreadUsageBase {

    @Around("@annotation(fairUsage)")
    public Object fairThreadUsageByEntity(final ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, final FairThreadUsageByEntity fairUsage)
            throws Throwable {  
        //Implementation
    }
}
```

The annotation does not work somehow. I am using AspectJWeaver 1.7 and java 1.7.
Let me know if anything else is needed. Any help appreciated.

EDIT: Adding controller as well which call getReport function

```
public class ReportDownloadRootController extends BaseRootController {
    public static final String REQUEST_MAPPING_REPORT_DOWNLOAD = "/hz/inventory/addproducts/status/report";
    public static final String PARAM_REFERENCE_ID = "reference_id";
    private AnInterface anInterface;

    @RequestMapping(REQUEST_MAPPING_REPORT_DOWNLOAD)
    public void execute(@RequestParam(value = PARAM_REFERENCE_ID, required = true) final String referenceId,
        final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) {
        try {

            Report report = AnInterface.getReport(referenceId, getContext().getMerchantId());    //breakpoint here
        } catch {
            //something
        }
    }
    @Resource(name = AnInterface.BEAN_NAME)
    public void setAnInterface(final AnInterface anInterface) {
        this.anInterface = anInterface;
    }
}
```

EDIT 2: Spring bean for `AnInterface`

```
<bean id="AnInterface" class="com.facade.feed.AnInterfaceImpl" />
```

Comment: Could be because you are using vanilla JDK proxies and they don't have access to the proxied object. What happens if you change `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />` to `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>` to use CGLIB?

Comment: @MikeKobit Not much have tried that option as well. Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9310927/aspect-not-executed-in-spring

Comment: Since you are using Spring AOP, I'm not sure what you mean by using `AspectJWeaver-1.7`. The `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />` allows you to use the `@Aspect` style annotations for AOP proxies. Can you verify by setting a breakpoint to see if your calls are a) being made through a proxy and b) that your advice being checked against?

Comment: @MikeKobit Please see the edit. I think it clarifies a few more things. I put a breakpoint at the point where get report is being called.Class named `Clib2AOPProxy` intercepts before the call is made to `getReport` but the advice is not being checked against.

Comment: The annotation on `AnInterfaceImpl.getReport(..)` should be `@FairThreadUsageByEntity`, not `@AnAnnotation`. Was that just a copy & paste problem or do you really use the wrong annotation there?

Comment: @kriegaex typo. edited.

Comment: I can see you declare (and use) annotation `@FairThreadUsageByEntity`, but you pointcut definition is `@annotation(fairUsage)`. Shouldn't is be `@annotation(full.package.for.FairThreadUsageByEntity)` ?

Comment: @SergeBallesta: No, the pointcut definition is correct, the type is specified in the advice signature and the annotation object bound to a parameter. This is how it is done is Spring AOP or AspectJ.

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam: I have tested your code in plain Java + AspectJ (outside Spring because I do not use Spring). The pointcut and advice are correct. I have no idea what your abstract base aspect does, you have not shown it. But anyway, it should work. If it does not, I simply suspect a Spring configuration issue. Do any of your other aspects work?

Comment: @kriegaex This is the only aspect I am using. Could you elaborate on "Suspect a spring configuration issue"?

Comment: It cannot be the only aspect because it inherits from another one. So there has to be at least one more parent aspect. And I cannot elaborate on the Spring configuration issue because I have never used Spring. Can you try a very simple aspect with a pointcut like `execution(* *(..))`? It should print a lot of stuff. If it does not, it is definitely a configuration problem. I am already 90% sure anyway.

Comment: Its likely that you'll have to provide more code, 'cause everything that you've posted looks correct. All, but one code, which I belieave is a type, but do want to check. In your controller it says private AnInterface anInterface; but this is a typo right? its the private AnInterface AnInterface; with the Autowired annotation set on it?

Comment: @MasterSlave I am using `@Resource` annotation (setter injection) so it is not a typo. The bean is injected properly. Did I get your concern right?

Comment: Even after all this discussion the issue does not seem to be solved. In order to not make this an endless discussion I recommend that you post a minimum, self-verifiable project (like a Gradle/Maven project) on Github that we can pull and try and help. I feel like there is some missing information here that will only lead to more back and forth.

Comment: @MikeKobit Apologies. I have not been able to find time recently and do not think that I will have time to work on this in recent future. Thanks for all help. Next time when I post something related to this, I will post the MWE as well.

Answer (score 0):

I created simple project with all provided by you information and can't reproduce your problem in simple setup, so you have correct implementation of your beans/aspects.

One possible and common error is defining aspect in one context and bean in another, for example aspect is defined in `applicationContext` and bean is defined in `dispatcherServletContext`. In such configuration aspect will not work on beans defined in child `dispatcherServletContext`, only in parent `applicationContext`